# Как спрятать элемент за правый край не расширяя страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Я изучаю CSS анимацию и моя задача в том, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку "Tell me more" с противоположных сторон страницы вылетали самолёты, которые изначально скрыты от глаз пользователя. Основная задача выполнена, но когда я пытаюсь спрятать правый самолёт за край, у меня расширяется страница. Как можно спрятать этот элемент не расширяя страницу?
[image: страница до выполнения js кода]

```js
function clickMe() {
  document.querySelector(".leftplane").classList.toggle("fly");
  document.querySelector(".rightplane").classList.toggle("fly2");
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  color: #222222;
}

div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

header {
  background: url(https://pp.userapi.com/c856132/v856132194/49221/7KsLUWQCMns.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
  height: 700px;
}

.container {
  width: 930px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button {
  background: #794b98;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: block;
  width: 240px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-top: 330px;
}

.leftplane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: -700px;
}

.rightplane {
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  right: -800px;
}

@keyframes fly {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  to {
    left: 880px;
  }
}

.fly {
  animation-name: fly;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.fly2 {
  animation-name: fly;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-direction: reverse;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="heading clearfix">
      <div>
        <a class="button" onclick="clickMe()">
    Tell me more
   </a>

        <img class="leftplane" src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/145795/isolated/preview/05cd33059a006bf49006097af4ccba98-plane-in-flight-by-vexels.png" />
        <img class="rightplane" src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/plane-hd-png-flight-image-free-png-in-sky-709.png" />

        <script>
          function clickMe() {
            document.querySelector(".leftplane").classList.toggle("fly");
            document.querySelector(".rightplane").classList.toggle("fly2");
          }
        </script>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</header>
```

[введите сюда описание изображения](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OscFE.png)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добавьте весь код так, чтобы визуализация отображалась.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прикольная фишка) 

Элементы слева и справа скрываются по разному, поэтому пришлось использовать разные подходы (в итоге получилось и вовсе без <s>регистрации и СМС</s> анимации и JS). 

Элемент слева можно скрыть как и вы. А справа - не убирать его за экран, а выдать нулевую ширину `width: 0;` В примере использованы пиксели, но смотрите еще в сторону `vw` — это единица, привязанная к ширине экрана.

Тег `<label>` позволяет переключать указанный чекбокс. А с этим переключением можно связать разные стили. Символ `~` означает, что второй элемент находится где-то ниже в коде от первого (и они оба не обернуты в какой-либо дополнительный тег).

Надо будет добавить в код `#planes {display: none;}` чтобы скрыть чекбокс.

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OPTlMUS/L76pmxsj/)

```css
.left {
  position: fixed;
  left: -180px; /* левый просто сдвинут налево */
  transition: 2s; /* transition обеспечивает плавный переход между состояниями */
}
.right {  
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  width: 0; /* а у правого нулевая ширина, т.е. он не выбивается за рамки страницы */
  height: 180px;
  overflow: hidden; /* чтобы не появлялся скролл во время раскрытия */
  transition: 2s;
}
/* Магия */
/* В теге <label> (она же кнопка) указано for="planes". 
Значит при клике на него, она найдет <input id="planes" ...> и переключит его.
Если классы в CSS записываются через точку .class, то id - через клетку, #planes
Для отмеченного состояния чекбокса есть специальный селектор, :checked

Когда он отмечен:
находим элемент с классом .left где-то ниже в коде и даем ему left: 0; 
(до этого было left: -180px) */
#planes:checked ~ .left { left: 0; }

/* Ключевой момент, что #planes находится выше в коде, чем остальные классы, 
и сам не обернут в какой-либо другой тег, чтобы ~ сработал.*/
/* По той же схеме находим блок .right ниже и даем ему width: 180px; */
#planes:checked ~ .right { width: 180px; }

/* Но label тоже находится ниже чекбокса, поэтому его переключения могут повлиять 
и на сам label. 
Запись двух элементов с пробелом означает, что второй находится ВНУТРИ другого .
Внутри label две "кнопки", одна изначально скрыта*/
.hide {display: none;}
/* Когда чекбокс отмечен, находим .button внутри label, который ниже #planes 
и делаем его(их) невидимым*/
#planes:checked ~ label .button {display: none;}
/* А потом находим .hide и делаем его видимым. 
Таким образом переключается текст в кнопке.*/
#planes:checked ~ label .hide {display: inline;}

/* Ненужные цвета кнопки */
.button {
  background-color: #7c1199;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 3px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.button:active {
  background-color: #045acf;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="planes">
  <label for="planes">
    <a class="button">Tell me more</a>
    <a class="button hide">Close...</a>
  </label>

  <br><br>
  <div class="left">
    <img src="https://gyazo.com/0d017714eb3a95acf9efc7caf9949112.png" />
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <img src="https://gyazo.com/0d017714eb3a95acf9efc7caf9949112.png"/>
  </div>

</div>
```

P.s. самолетики немного не те)

---

Если сильно хочется именно через @keyframes, можно просто переписать те же стили для отдельных классов и добавлять эти классы через JS, как вы пробовали.

Comment: ого, очень интересно, а не могли бы вы объяснить момент с магией? и ещё такой вопрос, у меня самолеты должны пересекать всю страницу, для этого я использовала @keyframes, ваш код тоже можно преобразовать к такой функции? насколько я поняла меняется ширина, но я могу ошибаться, так как не сильно поняла момент с магией))

Comment: *Добавил комментарии в самом коде) Параллельно смотрите на HTML во время чтения, чтобы было ясно, о чем речь. Анимашку также можно добавить именно под селектор, и там останется записать сдвиг через 2 секунды (анимация должна дождаться, чтобы width полностью раскрылось за 2 секунды от transition), `:checked ~ ... { animation: fly linear...; }`

Comment: теперь всё понятно, благодарю вас за детальное объяснение)

Answer (score 0):

Нашла простой ответ на свой вопрос, возможно, кому-то будет интересно.
На самом деле моя ошибка была в том, что я указывала положение в пикселях, из-за чего страница расширялась, когда я указала `right: 110%;`, то есть в процентах, страница перестала расширяться и всё остальное (анимация) работало с:

```css
.rightplane {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: 350px;
  top: 250px;
  right: 110%;
}
```